# Using multiple SQLite Databases in my android app project

Tags: java, android, sqlite

so i am currently programming an alarm clock app for android, which i am still learning and i was wondering if i should make a DBHelper class for every database that i create, or how i can handle multiple tables pointing to each other by ids. It's problematic for me, because i populate a RecyclerView with data from said tables. Now problems start to arise, as soon as i try to delete data at runtime, the table ids are all primary key autoincrement, so if i delete any element, this will cause the id to not represent the row number of the database table, sadly autoincrement doesnt handle ids to decrease if an item in a row before them is deleted.

At first i tried communicating the data for the alarms across multiple activities via sharedPreference, i wanted the data to persist if the app crashes for instance, so i switched to sqlite, i do have my DBHelper class, carrying all of the tables that i use:

```
package com.example.alarm;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Objects;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    
    Context context;

    public DBHelper(Context context, String db) {
        
        super(context, db, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create Table Alarmdatabase (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, label TEXT, method_queue_id INTEGER, sound_path_id INTEGER, privilege_rights INTEGER, snoozable INTEGER, time_wake_up_hours INTEGER, time_wake_up_minutes INTEGER, days_schedule_id INTEGER, weeks_schedule_id INTEGER, check_awake INTEGER, alarm_level_table_id INTEGER)");
        //every int representing a bool is -1 for false                         this is the id of the table and the item in it, for the corresponding method

        db.execSQL("create Table Methoddatabase (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, queue_id INTEGER, method_type_id INTEGER, method_id INTEGER, difficulty_id INTEGER, label TEXT, method_database_specific_id INTEGER)"); //multiple rows with same queue_id are part of the same queue
        db.execSQL("create Table Methodtype (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, method_type TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create Table Method (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, method TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create Table Difficulty (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, difficulty TEXT)");

        db.execSQL("create Table Alarmlevel (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, level_id INTEGER, method_databse_queue_id INTEGER)"); //multiple rows with the same level_id make up the different Alarmlevels, might add more attribs later

        db.execSQL("create Table QRBarcodedatabase (label TEXT primary key, decoded TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create Table Mathdatabase (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, method TEXT, difficulty TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create Table Locationdatabase (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, latitude_int INTEGER, zero_point_latitude INTEGER, longitude_int INTEGER, zero_point_longitude INTEGER, radius_int INTEGER, zero_point_radius INTEGER, street TEXT, radius_mode TEXT)");
        setupTablesForPreset(db);
    }

    private void setupTablesForPreset(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        long res;
        for(String type : new String[]{"tap_off","math","qr_barcode","location","sudoku","memory","passphrase"}) {
            cv.put("method_type", type);
            res = db.insert("Methodtype", null, cv);
            if(res == -1){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error setting up static Database \"Methodtype\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


        cv = new ContentValues();
        for(String type : new String[]{"null","add","sub","mult","div","fac","root","value_fx","extrema_fx","multiple_choice","reach_radius","leave_radius"}) {
            cv.put("method", type);
            res = db.insert("Method", null, cv);
            if(res == -1){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error setting up static Database \"Method\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


        cv = new ContentValues();
        for(String type : new String[]{"ex_easy","easy","middle","hard","ex_hard"}) {
            cv.put("difficulty", type);
            res = db.insert("Difficulty", null, cv);
            if(res == -1){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error setting up static Database \"Difficulty\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int verOld, int verNew) {
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Alarmdatabase");

        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Methoddatabase");
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Methodtype");
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Method");
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Difficulty");

        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Alarmlevel");

        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists QRBarcodedatabase");
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Mathdatabase");
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Locationdatabase");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //TODO: I don't need to handle SQLInjection, atleast for now, because sharing of settings is not supported as of now, so this would only harm the person itself, or be a nice niche feature lol
    //(this might change in the future, so i will keep this todo in until publishing, so if i add that feature at any point, i'll know, that i have to take care of that.)


    public void deleteRow(String table, int row_id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        long res = db.delete(table, "id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(row_id+2)});
        if(res ==0){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed deleting item: " + res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Success deleting item: " +res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public void deleteRow(String table, String label){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        long res = db.delete(table, "label=?", new String[]{label});

        if(res ==-1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed deleting item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Success deleting item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void addAlarm(String label, int methodQueueId, int soundPathId, boolean privilegeRights, boolean snoozable, int wakeUpTimeHours, int wakeUpTimeMinutes, int daysScheduleId, int weeksScheduleId, boolean checkAwake, int alarmLevelTableId){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("label", label);
        cv.put("method_queue_id",methodQueueId);
        cv.put("sound_path_id",soundPathId);
        if(privilegeRights){
        cv.put("privilege_rights",1);}
        else{
            cv.put("privilege_rights", 0);}
        if(snoozable){
        cv.put("snoozable",1);}
        else{
            cv.put("snoozable",0);}
        cv.put("time_wake_up_hours", wakeUpTimeHours);
        cv.put("time_wake_up_minutes", wakeUpTimeMinutes);
        cv.put("days_schedule_id",daysScheduleId);
        cv.put("weeks_schedule_id",weeksScheduleId);
        if(checkAwake){
        cv.put("check_awake", 1);}else{
            cv.put("check_awake", 0);}
        cv.put("alarm_level_table_id",alarmLevelTableId);
        long res = db.insert("Alarmdatabase", null, cv);
        if(res == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Inserting into Alarmdatabase failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added into Alarmdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    public void addMethod(int queueID, int methodTypeId, int methodId, int difficultyId, String label, int methodDatabaseSpecificID){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("queue_id",queueID);
        cv.put("method_type_id",methodTypeId);
        if(methodId != -1) cv.put("method_id",methodId);
        if(difficultyId != -1) cv.put("difficulty_id",difficultyId);
        if(!Objects.equals(label, "-1")) cv.put("label",label);
        cv.put("method_database_specific_id", methodDatabaseSpecificID);    //This is the id, that (if necessary) points to the specific data of the method database defined by method_type_id
                                                                            //In easy words: if you need to look up the decoded string from qrcode method, this points to the id in the specific database, that has this info
        long res = db.insert("Methoddatabase", null, cv);
        if(res == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Inserting into Methoddatabase failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added into Methoddatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    public String getMethodById(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Method WHERE ?", new String[]{"id =" + id});

        if(c.getCount() == 0){

            return "non existent";
        }else{
            c.moveToNext();
            return c.getString(1);
            }
        }


    public String getMethodTypeById(int id){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MethodType WHERE ?", new String[]{"id =" + id});

        if(c.getCount() > 0){

            c.moveToFirst();
            return c.getString(1);

        }else{
            return "non existent";


        }
    }

    public String getDifficulty(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Difficulty WHERE ?", new String[]{"id =" + id});

        if(c.getCount() == 0){

            return "non existent";
        }else{
            c.moveToNext();
            return c.getString(1);
        }
    }




    public int findIdByMethodType(String methodType){

        String[] methArr = new String[]{"tap_off","math","qr_barcode","location","sudoku","memory","passphrase"};
        for(int i = 0; i < methArr.length; i++) {
            if(methArr[i].equals(methodType)){
                return i+1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int findIdByMethod(String method){
        String[] meArr = new String[]{"null","Addition","Subtraction","Multiplication","Division","Faculty (x!)","Root","Value for f(x)","Determine extrema of f(x)","Multiple choice questions","reach_radius","leave_radius"};
        for(int i = 0; i < meArr.length; i++){
            if(meArr[i].equals(method)){
                return i+1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int findIdByDifficulty(String difficulty){
        switch (difficulty) {
            case "Extremely easy":
                return 1;
            case "Easy":
                return 2;
            case "Middle":
                return 3;
            case "Hard":
                return 4;
            case "Extremely hard":
                return 5;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }


    public void addMath(String method, String difficulty){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("method",method);
        cv.put("difficulty",difficulty);
        long res = db.insert("Mathdatabase", null, cv);
        if(res == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Inserting into Mathdatabase failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added into Mathdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void addQRBar(String label, String decoded){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("label", label);
        cv.put("decoded", decoded);
        long res = db.insert("QRBarcodedatabase", null, cv);
        if(res == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Inserting into QRBarcodedatabase failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added into QRBarcodedatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    //        Locationdatabase latitude_int INTEGER, zero_point_latitude INTEGER, longitude_int INTEGER, zero_point_longitude INTEGER, radius_int INTEGER, zero_point_radius INTEGER, street TEXT)");

    public long addLocation(int latitudeInt, int zeroPointLatitude, int longitudeInt, int zeroPointLongitude, int radiusInt, int zeroPointRadius, String street, String radiusMode){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("latitude_int",latitudeInt);
        cv.put("zero_point_latitude",zeroPointLatitude);
        cv.put("longitude_int",longitudeInt);
        cv.put("zero_point_longitude",zeroPointLongitude);
        cv.put("radius_int",radiusInt);
        cv.put("zero_point_radius",zeroPointRadius);
        cv.put("street",street);
        cv.put("radius_mode", radiusMode);
        long res = db.insert("Locationdatabase", null, cv);
        if(res == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Inserting into Locationdatabase failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added into Locationdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return res;
    }



    public void editMethoddatabase(int queue_id, int method_type_id, int method_id, int difficulty_id, String label, int method_database_spec_id, int row_id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        if(queue_id != -1) cv.put("queue_id", queue_id);
        if(method_type_id != -1) cv.put("method_type_id", method_type_id);
        if(method_id != -1) cv.put("method_id", method_id);
        if(difficulty_id != -1) cv.put("difficulty_id", difficulty_id);
        if(!Objects.equals(label,"-1")) cv.put("label", label);
        if(method_database_spec_id != -1) cv.put("method_database_specific_id", method_database_spec_id);

        if (method_id == 1){
            editMathdatabase(getMethodById(method_id), getDifficulty(difficulty_id), method_database_spec_id);
        }

        long result = db.update("Methoddatabase", cv, "id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(row_id)});
        if(result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to update Methoddatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Success updating Methoddatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    public void editMathdatabase(String method, String difficulty, int row_id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
        if (!Objects.equals(method, "")) c.put("method", method);
        if (!Objects.equals(difficulty, "")) c.put("difficulty", difficulty);

        long r = db.update("Mathdatabase",c, "id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(row_id)});
        if(r == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to update Mathdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Success updating Mathdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    public void editLocation(int lat, int zerolat, int lon, int zerolon, int radius, int zeroradius, String street, String enter_leave, int row_id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        int currlat, currzerolat, currlon, currzerolon, currradius, currzeroradius;
        String currstreet, currenterleave;

        Cursor c = getData("Locationdatabase");
        if(c.getCount() > 0) {
            while(c.moveToNext()){
                if(c.getInt(0) == row_id){

                    currlat = c.getInt(1);
                    currzerolat = c.getInt(2);
                    currlon = c.getInt(3);
                    currzerolon = c.getInt(4);
                    currradius = c.getInt(5);
                    currzeroradius = c.getInt(6);
                    currstreet = c.getString(7);
                    currenterleave = c.getString(8);

                    if (lat != currlat) cv.put("latitude_int", lat);
                    if (zerolat != currzerolat) cv.put("zero_point_latitude", zerolat);
                    if (lon != currlon) cv.put("longitude_int", lon);
                    if (zerolon != currzerolon) cv.put("zero_point_longitude", zerolon);
                    if (radius != currradius) cv.put("radius_int", radius);
                    if (zeroradius != currzeroradius) cv.put("zero_point_radius", zeroradius);
                    if (!Objects.equals(street, currstreet)) cv.put("street", street);
                    if (!Objects.equals(enter_leave,currenterleave)) cv.put("radius_mode", enter_leave);
                }
            }



            long res = db.update("Locationdatabase", cv, "id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(row_id)});
            if (res == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to update Locationdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Success updating Locationdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "how did you manage to even get here wtf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }





    public Cursor getData(String database ){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = null;

        if (db != null){
        c = db.rawQuery("Select * from "+database, null);
        }
        return c;
    }

    public Cursor execQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);

    }

}
```

To not confuse you: the alarm has a queue of methods to solve when turning off the alarm, methods as of now are settable for location(enter/leave radius), math tasks, scanning a qr/barcode, tapping off. I will implement a sudoku, memory and a typing your typephrase method. The Alarm should also be able to consist of different levels, so if you solve the first queue of methods, you can set x more method queues to come after that. Levels are not yet implemented, but will also be complicated when the ids are changing.

Does someone know, how i could change my code, so it wont get confused by deleting a method from the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`so if i delete any element, this will cause the id to not represent the row number of the database table`

This is fine. IDs shouldn't be linked to table rows.

Are you familiar with [foreign keys](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)? That is how you are supposed to build a relationship between multiple tables.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with that, thanks. Problem is, that e.g. the Methoddatabase has a key called "method_database_specific_id", which should be child to different tables, depending on the method_type_id. I don't see how i could implement this from the link you send me, atleast it is only talking about keys that point to 1 specific database. Should i restructure my database then?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i resorted to updating the database now. I have method_specific_id not as a foreign key, even though it is one, but it still works and a foreign key can also be set from more than 1 database.

Update of the Code:

```
package com.example.alarm;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Objects;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    
    Context context;

    public DBHelper(Context context, String db) {
        
        super(context, db, null, 1);
        this.context = context;


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create Table Alarmdatabase (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, label TEXT, method_queue_id INTEGER, privilege_rights INTEGER," +
                " time_wake_up_hours INTEGER, time_wake_up_minutes INTEGER, days_schedule_id INTEGER, weeks_schedule_id INTEGER, check_awake INTEGER," +
                " alarm_level_id INTEGER, foreign key (alarm_level_id) references Alarmlevel(id))");
        //every int representing a bool is -1 for false                                             //represents how many methods are in the queue
        //alarm_level_id points to the Alarmlevel Table which has the level specific labels, snooze settings, sounds, etc
        //if alarm levels not used, just set everything as alarm level 1

        db.execSQL("create Table Methoddatabase (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, queue_id INTEGER, method_type_id INTEGER, method_id INTEGER, difficulty_id INTEGER," +
                " label TEXT, method_database_specific_id INTEGER, foreign KEY(method_type_id) references Methodtype(id), foreign key (method_id) references Method(id)," +
                " foreign key (difficulty_id) references Difficulty(id), foreign key(label) references QRBarcodedatabase(label)," +
                " foreign KEY(queue_id) references Alarmlevel(id))");

        db.execSQL("create Table Methodtype (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, method_type TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create Table Method (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, method TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create Table Difficulty (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, difficulty TEXT)");

        db.execSQL("create Table Alarmlevel (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, label TEXT, snooze_count INTEGER, snooze_time INTEGER, sound_path TEXT)"); //multiple rows with the same level_id make up the different Alarmlevels, might add more attribs later

        db.execSQL("create Table QRBarcodedatabase (label TEXT primary key, decoded TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create Table Mathdatabase (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, method TEXT, difficulty TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create Table Locationdatabase (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, latitude_int INTEGER, zero_point_latitude INTEGER, longitude_int INTEGER," +
                " zero_point_longitude INTEGER, radius_int INTEGER, zero_point_radius INTEGER, street TEXT, radius_mode TEXT)");
        setupTablesForPreset(db);

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int verOld, int verNew) {
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Alarmdatabase");

        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Methoddatabase");
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Methodtype");
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Method");
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Difficulty");

        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Alarmlevel");

        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists QRBarcodedatabase");
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Mathdatabase");
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Locationdatabase");
        onCreate(db);
    }


    private void setupTablesForPreset(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        long res;
        for(String type : new String[]{"tap_off","math","qr_barcode","location","sudoku","memory","passphrase"}) {
            cv.put("method_type", type);
            res = db.insert("Methodtype", null, cv);
            if(res == -1){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error setting up static Database \"Methodtype\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


        cv = new ContentValues();
        for(String type : new String[]{"null","add","sub","mult","div","fac","root","value_fx","extrema_fx","multiple_choice","reach_radius","leave_radius"}) {
            cv.put("method", type);
            res = db.insert("Method", null, cv);
            if(res == -1){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error setting up static Database \"Method\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


        cv = new ContentValues();
        for(String type : new String[]{"ex_easy","easy","middle","hard","ex_hard"}) {
            cv.put("difficulty", type);
            res = db.insert("Difficulty", null, cv);
            if(res == -1){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error setting up static Database \"Difficulty\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }



    }

    /**
     * @param database: the string of the table in database.db
     * @return the max id in the table, if db empty it returns 0
     */
    public int getMaxTableId(String database){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT max(id) FROM " + database, null);
        if(c1.getCount() >0){
            int id = 0;
            c1.moveToFirst();
            id = c1.getInt(0);
            c1.close();

            return id;
        }
        return 0;
    }


    //TODO: I don't need to handle SQLInjection, atleast for now, because sharing of settings is not supported as of now, so this would only harm the person itself, or be a nice niche feature lol
    //(this might change in the future, so i will keep this todo in until publishing, so if i add that feature at any point, i'll know, that i have to take care of that.)


    public void deleteRow(String table, int row_id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        long res = db.delete(table, "id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(row_id)});
        if(res ==0){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed deleting item: " + res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Success deleting item: " +res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public void addAlarm(String label, int methodQueueId, int soundPathId, boolean privilegeRights, boolean snoozable, int wakeUpTimeHours, int wakeUpTimeMinutes, int daysScheduleId, int weeksScheduleId, boolean checkAwake, int alarmLevelTableId){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("label", label);
        cv.put("method_queue_id",methodQueueId);
        cv.put("sound_path_id",soundPathId);
        if(privilegeRights){
        cv.put("privilege_rights",1);}
        else{
            cv.put("privilege_rights", 0);}
        if(snoozable){
        cv.put("snoozable",1);}
        else{
            cv.put("snoozable",0);}
        cv.put("time_wake_up_hours", wakeUpTimeHours);
        cv.put("time_wake_up_minutes", wakeUpTimeMinutes);
        cv.put("days_schedule_id",daysScheduleId);
        cv.put("weeks_schedule_id",weeksScheduleId);
        if(checkAwake){
        cv.put("check_awake", 1);}else{
            cv.put("check_awake", 0);}
        cv.put("alarm_level_table_id",alarmLevelTableId);
        long res = db.insert("Alarmdatabase", null, cv);
        if(res == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Inserting into Alarmdatabase failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added into Alarmdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    public void addMethod(int id, int queueID, int methodTypeId, int methodId, int difficultyId, String label, int methodDatabaseSpecificID){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("queue_id",queueID);
        cv.put("method_type_id",methodTypeId);
        if(methodId != -1) cv.put("method_id",methodId);
        if(difficultyId != -1) cv.put("difficulty_id",difficultyId);
        if(!Objects.equals(label, "-1")) cv.put("label",label);
        cv.put("method_database_specific_id", methodDatabaseSpecificID);    //This is the id, that (if necessary) points to the specific data of the method database defined by method_type_id
                                                                            //In easy words: if you need to look up the decoded string from qrcode method, this points to the id in the specific database, that has this info
        long res = db.insert("Methoddatabase", null, cv);
        if(res == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Inserting into Methoddatabase failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added into Methoddatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    public String getMethodById(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Method WHERE ?", new String[]{"id =" + id});

        if(c.getCount() == 0){

            return "non existent";
        }else{
            c.moveToNext();
            return c.getString(1);
            }
        }


    public String getMethodTypeById(int id){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MethodType WHERE ?", new String[]{"id =" + id});

        if(c.getCount() > 0){

            c.moveToFirst();
            return c.getString(1);

        }else{
            return "non existent";


        }
    }

    public String getDifficulty(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Difficulty WHERE ?", new String[]{"id =" + id});

        if(c.getCount() == 0){

            return "non existent";
        }else{
            c.moveToNext();
            return c.getString(1);
        }
    }




    public int findIdByMethodType(String methodType){

        String[] methArr = new String[]{"tap_off","math","qr_barcode","location","sudoku","memory","passphrase"};
        for(int i = 0; i < methArr.length; i++) {
            if(methArr[i].equals(methodType)){
                return i+1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int findIdByMethod(String method){
        String[] meArr = new String[]{"null","Addition","Subtraction","Multiplication","Division","Faculty (x!)","Root","Value for f(x)","Determine extrema of f(x)","Multiple choice questions","reach_radius","leave_radius"};
        for(int i = 0; i < meArr.length; i++){
            if(meArr[i].equals(method)){
                return i+1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int findIdByDifficulty(String difficulty){
        switch (difficulty) {
            case "Extremely easy":
                return 1;
            case "Easy":
                return 2;
            case "Middle":
                return 3;
            case "Hard":
                return 4;
            case "Extremely hard":
                return 5;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }


    public void addMath(String method, String difficulty){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("method",method);
        cv.put("difficulty",difficulty);
        long res = db.insert("Mathdatabase", null, cv);
        if(res == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Inserting into Mathdatabase failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added into Mathdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void addQRBar(String label, String decoded){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("label", label);
        cv.put("decoded", decoded);
        long res = db.insert("QRBarcodedatabase", null, cv);
        if(res == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Inserting into QRBarcodedatabase failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added into QRBarcodedatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    //        Locationdatabase latitude_int INTEGER, zero_point_latitude INTEGER, longitude_int INTEGER, zero_point_longitude INTEGER, radius_int INTEGER, zero_point_radius INTEGER, street TEXT)");

    public long addLocation(int latitudeInt, int zeroPointLatitude, int longitudeInt, int zeroPointLongitude, int radiusInt, int zeroPointRadius, String street, String radiusMode){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("latitude_int",latitudeInt);
        cv.put("zero_point_latitude",zeroPointLatitude);
        cv.put("longitude_int",longitudeInt);
        cv.put("zero_point_longitude",zeroPointLongitude);
        cv.put("radius_int",radiusInt);
        cv.put("zero_point_radius",zeroPointRadius);
        cv.put("street",street);
        cv.put("radius_mode", radiusMode);
        long res = db.insert("Locationdatabase", null, cv);
        if(res == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Inserting into Locationdatabase failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added into Locationdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return res;
    }


    public long addLevel(int id, String label, int snooze_count, int snooze_time, String sound_path){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        if(snooze_count != -2) cv.put("snooze_count", snooze_count);
        if(snooze_time != -1) cv.put("snooze_time", snooze_time);
        if(label != null) cv.put("label", label);
        if(!Objects.equals(sound_path, "-1")) cv.put("sound_path", sound_path);

        long result = db.insert("Alarmlevel", null, cv);
        if(result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Inserting into Alarmlevel failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added into Alarmlevel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return result;

    }



    public void editLevel(int id, String label, int snooze_count, int snooze_time, String sound_path){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        if(snooze_count != -2) cv.put("snooze_count", snooze_count);
        if(snooze_time != -1) cv.put("snooze_time", snooze_time);
        if(!Objects.equals(label, "-1")) cv.put("label", label);
        if(!Objects.equals(sound_path, "-1")) cv.put("sound_path", sound_path);

        long result = db.update("Alarmlevel", cv, "id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        if(result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to update alarm level", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Success updating alarm level", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }





    public void editMethoddatabase(int queue_id, int method_type_id, int method_id, int difficulty_id, String label, int method_database_spec_id, int row_id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        if(queue_id != -1) cv.put("queue_id", queue_id);
        if(method_type_id != -1) cv.put("method_type_id", method_type_id);
        if(method_id != -1) cv.put("method_id", method_id);
        if(difficulty_id != -1) cv.put("difficulty_id", difficulty_id);
        if(!Objects.equals(label,"-1")) cv.put("label", label);
        if(method_database_spec_id != -1) cv.put("method_database_specific_id", method_database_spec_id);

        if (method_id == 1){
            editMathdatabase(getMethodById(method_id), getDifficulty(difficulty_id), method_database_spec_id);
        }

        long result = db.update("Methoddatabase", cv, "id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(row_id)});
        if(result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to update Methoddatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Success updating Methoddatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    public void editMathdatabase(String method, String difficulty, int row_id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
        if (!Objects.equals(method, "")) c.put("method", method);
        if (!Objects.equals(difficulty, "")) c.put("difficulty", difficulty);

        long r = db.update("Mathdatabase",c, "id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(row_id)});
        if(r == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to update Mathdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Success updating Mathdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    public void editLocation(int lat, int zerolat, int lon, int zerolon, int radius, int zeroradius, String street, String enter_leave, int row_id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        int currlat, currzerolat, currlon, currzerolon, currradius, currzeroradius;
        String currstreet, currenterleave;

        Cursor c = getData("Locationdatabase");
        if(c.getCount() > 0) {
            while(c.moveToNext()){
                if(c.getInt(0) == row_id){

                    currlat = c.getInt(1);
                    currzerolat = c.getInt(2);
                    currlon = c.getInt(3);
                    currzerolon = c.getInt(4);
                    currradius = c.getInt(5);
                    currzeroradius = c.getInt(6);
                    currstreet = c.getString(7);
                    currenterleave = c.getString(8);

                    if (lat != currlat) cv.put("latitude_int", lat);
                    if (zerolat != currzerolat) cv.put("zero_point_latitude", zerolat);
                    if (lon != currlon) cv.put("longitude_int", lon);
                    if (zerolon != currzerolon) cv.put("zero_point_longitude", zerolon);
                    if (radius != currradius) cv.put("radius_int", radius);
                    if (zeroradius != currzeroradius) cv.put("zero_point_radius", zeroradius);
                    if (!Objects.equals(street, currstreet)) cv.put("street", street);
                    if (!Objects.equals(enter_leave,currenterleave)) cv.put("radius_mode", enter_leave);
                }
            }



            long res = db.update("Locationdatabase", cv, "id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(row_id)});
            if (res == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to update Locationdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Success updating Locationdatabase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "how did you manage to even get here wtf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }





    public Cursor getData(String database ){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = null;

        if (db != null){
        c = db.rawQuery("Select * from "+database, null);
        }
        return c;
    }

    public Cursor execQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);

    }

}
```